# Opacity in a menu, but not on a list

Tags: html, css, opacity

I am going to make this short, so it's easy to understand.

This is the scenario:

- I am having opacity in the menu (this works)
- I am trying to remove the opacity from the popup (*last li, #myModal*) (this does not work)

**Some of the html in the header:**

```
<div id="header_menu">
   <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"><img src=<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/innbokskontroll_nav_menu.png height="15px"></label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
   <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="http://sookvisuals.com/dev/innbokskontroll/referanser/">referanser</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://sookvisuals.com/dev/innbokskontroll/blogg">blogg</a></li>
      <li class="popupp"><a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-custom" data-toggle="modal">bestill foredrag!</a>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div><!-- End of Modal body -->
      </div><!-- End of Modal content -->
      </div><!-- End of Modal dialog -->
      </div>       
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I am sorry if this is a messy HTML. I tried to make it simple to understand here on SO.

**The currently CSS which adds opacity to the menu is the following:**

```
#header_menu {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

**To remove the opacity I have tried the following, but it does not work:**

```
#myModal {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.modal-content, .modal-dialog {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    text-align: left;
}

li.popupp {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Could you please help me to find the solution?

Comment: not possible. the opacity goes to the childs. you have to make sibling divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `opacity` try to use `rgba` like below.

```
 #header_menu
{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 }
```

So this will not affect any child elements. So wherever you want opacity you can use it like above. The only thing you need to give it `rgb` format.

Comment: what if he also needs to change opacity of the content?

Comment: that is normal. you can use his original code. Suppose if you want to do opacity some particular element inside the `header_menu` you can apply as mentioned like `#header_menu, ul#menu{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);}`